# Converting worded CSS values to numerical

Tags: javascript, css, computed-style

When I call `window.getComputedStyle()` on an element and try to get a property such as lineHeight, which can have both worded and numerical values, is there a way or a different function that will return a numerical value every time?

My `line-height` example refers to the `normal` keyword. Other examples include font weights and border widths. All these use keywords but map to numerical values.

Comment: You could write a function you can call in-line that checks for a numeric value and if not, uses a switch to decide what to return based on the text. At least that's probably what I'd do.

Comment: Do you mean both worded and numerical, like this: `15px` ?

Comment: if you want width or height, you can use `elem.offsetWidth` and `elem.offsetHeight` respectively. where `elem` is element holding variable.

Comment: no I mean keywords not units. The line height example refers to the 'normal' keyword. Other examples include font weights and border widths. All these use keywords but map to numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the fact that the return value can contain `px` or other units, you can use the `parseInt` function:

```
function getTheStyle(elem,property)
{
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(property);
    return parseInt(theCSSprop);
}

var element = document.getElementById('test');
alert(getTheStyle(element,"height"));
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6vQV/). Instead of returning `100px` it returns `100`

You can extract the units like so:

```
var str = "100em";
var matches = str.match(/([a-z]+)$/gi);
alert(matches);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PYA4/)

Edit:

Apparently, `normal` can be set to a "reasonable" value by the user agent, and is font-specific, where the spec recommends it be between 1.0 and 1.2. So you would probably [be better off](http://jsfiddle.net/CWw6d/) calculating it's `height` property.

> **normal**
>   Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
>   on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as
>   <[number](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-number)>. We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2.
>   The computed value is '[normal](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#computed-value)'.

Here's an in depth [blog post](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/) about it.

Comment: By your code, `100px == 100em == 100cm`... somehow I doubt this is correct, or what OP was after!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Good point. I was assuming he would know what the units were.

Comment: If OP doesn't even know if they'll be getting a number *or a string* (ie. keyword), your assumption was rather rash :p

Comment: indeed, the line height example refers to the 'normal' keyword. Other examples include font weights and border widths. All these use keywords but map to numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because there is not always a mapping.

Example:

```
<div></div>
```

JS:

```
alert(getComputedStyle(document.body.children[0]).width);
// alerts "auto"
```

Now... what numeric value would satisfy that?